# Resonance in a gravitational field?

Tags: gravity

Assume that there are only well behaved functions as mass distributions, and there are no other forces except gravitation. Is it than possible to create an arrangement where a variation of a certain quantity (could be mass density or gravitational field or momentum) has a resonance?

Comment: What do you mean by "variation"? And also, what do you mean by "resonance structure" exactly? I'm not sure whether you're talking about the same thing that physicists mean when they say "resonance."

Comment: @David Zaslavsky: i mean a variation in time or space. By resonance i mean an exponentially damped sinusoid .

Comment: So you're asking whether it's possible, using only gravitational forces, to create a situation in which some physical quantity $q$ has values given by an exponentially damped sinusoidal function of time, $q(t) \sim e^{-t/\tau}\cos(\omega t)$? If so, it seems like an odd question to ask. (In any case, "resonance structure" is almost certainly the wrong term to use here)

Comment: @David Zaslavsky: edited.

Comment: @David Zaslavsky: I want to get hold of the mathematical nature of the gravitational field when only well behaved mass distributions are allowed !

Comment: @Rajesh: okay, fair enough, it just seemed odd! I'm just trying to understand your question. Anyway, even "resonance" is not the right word, I think. A resonance occurs when an oscillator is subject to some external influence that also oscillates at the same frequency as the natural frequency of the oscillator. Again, I may be misunderstanding, but it doesn't seem like that's what you're asking about.

Comment: @David Zaslavsky: It is not necessary for the external influence to be a sinusoid !

Comment: @Rajesh: of course not, it may oscillate at other frequencies as well and thereby be a non-sinusoidal signal. I simply meant that in the Fourier decomposition of the driving force, there must be a nonzero component at the resonant frequency of the oscillator. Still, that doesn't sound like what you're asking about.

Comment: @David Zaslavsky: I want to look at Gravitational field with continuous mass distribution as a system with certain input and an output. Variation of a certain $q$ in space/time is an input to the system and variation of certain $r$ in space/time as output. Now i want to study what is the nature of such a system in general.

Comment: "Resonance in a gravitational field" makes me thing about that: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_resonance . But your question is strangely stated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A matter distribution with a sinsuoidally varying monopole or dipole moment will only produce variations in the gravitational field within the matter distribution.  If the quadrupole (or a higher multipole moment) varies sinsuoidally, you will produce gravitational waves in a way very analogous to how electromagnetic waves are produced, with the amplitude differing by just a few numeric constants.

I wouldn't expect the back-reaction of the wave to amplify the variation that created the wave in the first place, though.  Is this what you mean by 'a resonance'?

Comment: @Jerry Schirmer: what do you mean by a monopole and a dipole ?

Comment: Monopole moment: $M=\int d^{3}x\left(\rho\right)$.  Dipole moment: $P^{i}=\int d^{3}x\left( x^{i}\rho\right)$.  Quadrupole moment: $Q^{ij}=\int d^{3}x\left( x^{i}x^{j}\rho\right)$.  There are further modifications that one can make if you are looking to make equations simpler (namely, subtracting traces of the quadrupole moment from itself), but that's the basic idea.

Comment: @Jerry Schirmer: please explain me in english without any notations

Comment: the monopole moment is the total amount of mass.  The dipole moment is the amount of mass current flow.  The quadrupole moment is more complicated, but is related to the moment of inertia from an intro physics course.  But these things are best described with equations.

Comment: @Jerry Schirmer: do you mean dipole moment is momentum ?

Comment: @Jerry Schirmer: and Quadpole the curl of the mass current flow vector field ?

Comment: The second thing is certainly false.  The time derivative of the dipole moment gives you the momentum of the matter distribution.  But they are really just those integrals.